Using Selenium to Navigate the Pages but the Webpage Keeps Returning to the First Page
I am trying to extract data of funding opportunities from the (https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/calls-for-proposals?isExactMatch=true&status=31094501,31094502&order=DESC&pageNumber=1&pageSize=50&sortBy=startDate) website, but Selenium keeps reverting to the first page. I think the clicking does work, but it just keeps showing me the first-page again and again.
There are 10 more pages that I should be extracting data from. I also tried formatting the url to increment the pageNumber=1 inside the URL, no good. The webpage itself keeps going back to pageNumber 1 when I manually increase it by the link. I don't know what to do.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 

def accept_cookies():
    try:
        cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.wt-ecl-button.wt-ecl-button--primary.cck-actions-button")))
        cookies_button.click()
        print("Cookies accepted.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error accepting cookies:", e)

def accept_button(driver):
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button' and contains(@class,'eui-button') and contains(@class,'eui-button--basic') and contains(@class,'eui-button--icon-only') and contains(@class,'eui-button--rounded')]")))
        button.click()
        print("Button accepted.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error accepting button:", e)
# Accept cookies if present


while True:
    url = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/calls-for-proposals?order=DESC&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&isExactMatch=true"

    driver.get(url)
    accept_cookies()
    # Wait until the elements are visible
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    opportunity_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.eui-u-text-link.eui-u-font-l.eui-u-font-regular')))
    deadline_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.eui-u-display-block.eui-u-mt-xs.ng-star-inserted')
    url_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.eui-u-text-link')
    
    #Extract data from the current page
    for i in range(len(opportunity_elements)):
        # Name
        try:
            opportunity_name = opportunity_elements[i].text
            k += 1
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
        # Deadline
        try:
            opportunity_deadline = deadline_elements[i].text if i < len(deadline_elements) else "Deadline not available"
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            opportunity_deadline = "No Deadline"
        # URL
        try:
            opportunity_url = url_elements[i].get_attribute('href')
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            opportunity_url = "No URL Available"
        
        data_list.append({
                'Opportunity Name': opportunity_name,
                'Deadline': opportunity_deadline,
                'URL': opportunity_url
            })

        print(f"Opportunity: {opportunity_name}, Deadline: {opportunity_deadline}, URL: {opportunity_url}")
    
    #Check if there is a next page
    accept_button(driver)
    
driver.quit()

This is the code that keeps and keeps extracting the first page.

This code snippet clicks the Next page button successfully.
The steps:

Wait for the Next page button to be clickable to make sure the page is fully loaded.
Scroll to the bottom of the page using JS. (This is to avoid clicking the cookies banner. You can also accept or otherwise dismiss that banner.)
Click the Next page button.

The code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/calls-for-proposals?isExactMatch=true&status=31094501,31094502&order=DESC&pageNumber=1&pageSize=50&sortBy=startDate"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for i in range(1,5):
    loader_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.eui-block-document__loader")
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(loader_locator))
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(loader_locator))

    print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "eui-card-header-title"))).text) # first heading
    next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "eui-icon-svg[aria-label='Go to next page']")))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    next_button.click()

Output
European Researchers' Night and Researchers at Schools 2026-2027
Electronic components
New knowledge and innovations for climate-smart farming - connecting research stations
European partnership for pandemic preparedness
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.


Thank you for your answer but I keep getting "element click intercepted. Other element would receive the click" error.

I gave this a try. It successfully clicked the button but it still keeps reverting back to the first page. next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "eui-icon-svg[aria-label='Go to next page']")))         actions = ActionChains(driver)         actions.move_to_element(next_button).perform()         driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 100);")  # Scroll 500 pixels down         next_button.click()

Are you running exactly my code? I put the scroll window step in there to avoid the click intercepted. The cookie banner at the bottom of the page is causing that issue so you either need to scroll it off the bottom of the page (as I did) or dismiss it in some way.

I ran your code on another file and it still gave an error on its own, unfortunately. raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <eui-icon-svg icon="eui-caret-right" aria-label="Go to next page" fillcolor="primary" aria-disabled="false" role="img" class="eui-icon-svg eui-icon-svg--">...</eui-icon-svg> is not clickable at point (1285, 10). Other element would receive the click: <eui-header _ngcontent-ng-c221419338="" class="eui-header">...</eui-header>

In my code, you can see that I defined a cookie click function. Problem after this isn't its being unable to click: it clicks; loads another page but the page it loaded is again the first page...

It's not loading the same page. You likely haven't properly waited for the next page to load so your getting the same info from the first page, etc. I've updated my code and this works. It loads new pages, waits for each page to properly load, etc.

The code you updated can click the next page button, but the problem of its reverting back to the first page remains. Even if you successfully click, it goes back to the homepage and I can't extract any data except page 1's.

I don't know what to tell you. It works fine on my machine as you can see in the output it's printing data from 5 different pages. You are running my code and only my code?
